# search item position

Tags: android, search

I am developing an Android application in which I am using a listview and search bar. When I click on any searched item it will show starting items, not the clicked one.

Can anyone help me how to get the position of selected item?

Comment: can you provide some code..

Comment: how did you implement your search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for getting position of your selected Item

```
YourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            SelectedId = YourList.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2);}});
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `getItemIdAtPosition()` method.

**Eg:**

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ProductList);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductDetails.class);
                // i.putExtra("keyAapo", arg2 );

                i.putExtra("keyAapo", (int) lv.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2));

                startActivity(i);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, while clicking the `listview` item,

1. get the `position` of that item in `listview`
2. Pass the `strings`/`values` to that `intent` if any.
3. Intent for navigating to next `class` as below:

   ```
    YourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {
           Cursor listItem = (Cursor)<YourListView>.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   String lID = listItem.getString(1); 
           Intent i= new Intent(<ClassName>.this, <Navigate to Class>.class)
                   i.putExtra("lID", lID); // key-value pair
       startActivity(i);
       }});
   ```